# Where to Initialize API Keys (eg: Amplitude) in a React Native App (with Expo + Redux)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, amplitude-analytics

Using a [React Native boiler plate with Expo and Redux](https://github.com/Keftaa/expo-redux-boilerplate), we like to use the Amplitude tracking service which involves first initializing with

```
Amplitude.initialize(apiKey)
```

followed by logging events in various React Components, such as

```
Amplitude.logEvent(eventName)
```

**Question:** Where in the React Native app structure (especially in the [linked boilerplate](https://github.com/Keftaa/expo-redux-boilerplate)) will you place the `Amplitude.initialize(apiKey)` code?

It works when the code is placed in the `componentDidMount` function of the `Setup` component in [`/src/boot/setup.js`](https://github.com/Keftaa/expo-redux-boilerplate/blob/master/src/boot/setup.js), but is that the best place to place it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I am not really into `react-native` but, this question is interesting for me.

I've read some articles and I believe this answer is a [hit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44908148/8861638), since it included almost a summarized research about this topic.

Also, possible approach to take is having your keys encrypted via [JWT](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/jwt-with-rsa-encryption) at your Back-side, then, requested and decrypted via Front-end?

Comment: Thats a great topic, and I am storing the sensitive secrets such as API keys in a `.env` file while which is then pulled by a npm/babel package. I believe regular React apps can do this easily, its just a lot trickier in react native apps.

Comment: I really hoped that would help, I know it's a lil bit complix to do it since you have almost no control about the environment where the app runs _Android_

Comment: Hope you find a way that fits!